# Output the mysql query results in rmarkdown

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, rmysql

I am getting crazy because I have written a sql query under the RMySQL package in a rmarkdown document and I dont get the output of the query in the document, but yes in the code editor.
I want to know how to get the output in the my document.

I need help because I search much around the web and I found nothing.

Comment: Hi there, can you please clarify a few things. Which editor are you using, and why are you expecting to see the results of a query in a static markdown document? Is it simply that you want to write a query in the editor and have the editor replace it with the results?

Comment: Hi =). I was using rstudio and I was written in rmarkdown, and I want that outputs me the result and the query in the result document =).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the code chunk feature instead of inline code, as detailed in the documentation for rmarkdown here:

[Code Chunks](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html)

This differs from inline code, in that the results can be put in the document **as well as** the query itself.

Comment: I posted an image in web, I have, in fact, written a code chunk but I dont get the output of the sentence: http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2rc9avn&s=9#.WD1hu-bhCM8. Here is what I want to make, thanks for the help =)

Comment: @RaulContreras try adding the Include=True option as mentioned on the page.

Comment: When I pass this option happens that not ouputs me the chunk but also the result

Comment: @RaulContreras so you only want the results and not the SQL query?

Comment: I want both of them, the result and the query

Comment: @RaulContreras as per the documentation I provided, it looks like you need include=true and echo=true